# Subscribe to an observable and put values into an array

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript, observable

I'm new in angular and I need some help.
I have an observable getting users of type User[]

```
User: [
id: string,
name: string
]
```

and I have another array Ids of type string getting the ids of the selected users from a mat-select

```
 Ids = this.Form.controls['users'].value
```

what I need right now is to subscribe to users$ observable, and get only the users that they have an id in Ids

```
 const selectedUsers = ids.forEach(id =>this.usersSub$.value.filter((user) => user.userId === id))
```

something like the above but it is not really the right thing to do because it returns undefined . I'm wondering how should I properly get my selectedUsers array.

Comment: That's not exactly an Angular problem, rather than a Javascript problem. Please show us what you tried so far.

Comment: My first struggle is how to subscribe to the observable and put the values into an array

Comment: That's how you subscribe to something: https://rxjs.dev/guide/subscription

Comment: Yes I got that but whenever I try to subscribe and put values into array I get this error "Type 'Subscription' is missing the following properties from type 'User[]': length, pop, push, concat, and 28 more."

Comment: paste your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use combineLatest to merge both observables and map all elements to accomplish it.

First, Create an observable with ids.

```
selectedIds$ = of([1, 3]);
  players$ = of([
    { id: 1, name: 'lebron' },
    { id: 2, name: 'irving' },
    { id: 3, name: 'love' },
  ]);
```

Next, combine both observables, using the `combineLatest` operator, and return the players using the map to iterate over the response from the combineLast, use the filter and find to match the playerid with the ids from the selectedIds array.

```
const seletedUsers$ = combineLatest([this.selectedIds$, 
     this.players$])
          .pipe(
            map(([ids, players]) => {
              return players.filter((p) => ids.find((id) => id === p.id));
            })
          )
          .subscribe((v) => {
            console.log(v);
          });
```

- https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/combineLatest
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Comment: That's good but selectedPlayers in my case is an array and I need to get players from the observable that they have the same ids in selectedPlayers array

Comment: @user8845321, I update my solution using an array of ids.

Comment: Thank you so much, but here it is returning selectedUsers$ observable right? And I need the selectedUsers array how could I get it